# Unable to add multiple receivers in alertmanager.yml file

Tags: yaml, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to add slack and email as receivers of my Prometheus alert manager, but it always return an error! :/

> Checking 'alertmanager.yml'  FAILED: yaml: unmarshal errors:
> line 11: field receivers not found in type config.plain
>
> amtool: error: failed to validate 1 file(s)

Here is the code (receivers: is the line# 11):

```
route:
  group_by:
    - alertname
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 1h
  receivers:
    - slack-notifications
    - email-me
```

Comment: 1. Configuration questions are off-topic for SO. For this kind of topics there [su], [sf] and [devops.se] (depending on your situation chose one)

Comment: 2. [`route`](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#route) accepts only one receiver.

Comment: How do I add two receivers then?